# Mips - Address out of range when attempting to load value from an array

Tags: arrays, runtime-error, mips

What I need to do is write the function rot1 so that it rotates an array of any size like 10,20,30,40 -> 40,30,20,10. I get an address out of range error on one of the lines (see swap function) though and I'm completely stuck. Would someone mind putting me on the right track?

```
    .data
    .align  2
a1: .word     10,20,30,40   # first array, size 4


    .text
    la  $a0,a1
    li  $a1,4
    jal rotl

rotl:
    addi    $sp,$sp,-8  # Save $s0 and $s1 on the stack
    sw  $s0,0($sp)
    sw  $s1,4($sp)

# Finding end of array (array size of 4 ending would be 12)
    subi    $t3,$a1,1
    add $t3,$t3,$t3
    add $t3,$t3,$t3 # end of array

# loading inital values
    li  $t2,0   # first value in array
    li  $s1,0   # s1 is our loop counter


swap:   slt $t0,$s1,$a1 # See if we're done yet
    beq $t0,$zero,rotdone   # exit loop if s1 >= a1 (i.e., if counter >= array size)
    add $t2,$t2,$a0 
    add $t3,$t3,$a0 
    lw  $t1,($t2)   # store first index value (10) in $t1 ##Error here: line 149: Runtime exception at 0x00400190: address out of range 0x20020004
    lw  $t4,($t3)   # store last index value (40) in $t4
    sw  $t4,($t2)   # swap first index value for last index value (10->40) 
    sw  $t1,($t3)   # swap last index value for first index value (40->10)
    addi    $t2,$t2,4   # add 4 to $t2 so we move to next index (20)
    subi    $t3,$t3,4   #sub 4 from $t3 so we move back an index (30)
    addi    $s1,$s1,1   # add 1 to loop counter
    j   swap
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code. From the example you gave you are not trying to do a rotation but a reversal (a rotation from `10,20,30,40` would be `40,10,20,30` but you stated it should result `40,30,20,10`).
So, assuming you are trying to do a reversal, then you should:

- swap only half times (in your example you are swapping 4 times, the first two would perform the actual reversal, the last two would bring back the original sequence)
- remove the addition of `$t2` and `$t3` with `$a0` from the swap loop. You should load those registers only once before the swapping begins
- Check what you'll do after the `rotl` routine ends, as it is written it will continue to execute the swap again

To summarize, this may fix the first two issues:

```
    add $a1, $a1, 1
    srl $a1, $a1, 1 
    move $t2, $a0
    add $t3, $t3, $a0

swap:   
    slt $t0,$s1,$a1 # See if we're done yet
    beq $t0,$zero,rotdone   # exit loop if s1 >= a1 (i.e., if counter >= array size)
    lw  $t1,($t2)   # store first index value (10) in $t1 
    lw  $t4,($t3)   # store last index value (40) in $t4
    sw  $t4,($t2)   # swap first index value for last index value (10->40) 
    sw  $t1,($t3)   # swap last index value for first index value (40->10)
    addi    $t2,$t2,4   # add 4 to $t2 so we move to next index (20)
    subi    $t3,$t3,4   #sub 4 from $t3 so we move back an index (30)
    addi    $s1,$s1,1   # add 1 to loop counter
    j   swap
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. You actually made me realize I _was_ supposed to rotate the array. I mistook rotation to be reversal.